# DLL File Format change to 3.5 .net version

Tags: .net, dll

I had a DLL file format of net version 4.5, I need to build the DLL file to .net version 3.5. I did not know how to start i search lot through googling but i got nothing . please help me who to change the DLL file format of net version 4.5 to DLL file to .net version 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project, simply right-click on the project, select properties, and choose target framework ".Net Framework 3.5".

This will produce a .Net 3.5 dll from your project.

If you're asking how to convert an existing dll from 4.5 to 3.5, then that is not possible.